# Why KafkaTemplate does not close tansactional producers?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have written a simple Kafka app with **spring integration kafka 3.2.1.RELEASE** and **kafka-clients 2.5** to learn kafka transactions.

It recieves the messages from a topic and sends them to another topic. The beans.xml file is as follows

```
    <int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter
            listener-container="container"
            auto-startup="true"
            send-timeout="30000"
            channel="channelA"/>
   <bean id="container"  class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer" parent="kafkaMessageListenerContainerAbstract">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.ContainerProperties">
                <constructor-arg
                        name="topics"
                        value="test"/>
                <property name="transactionManager" ref="KafkaTransactionManager"/>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
.
.
.
    <int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter kafka-template="kafkaTemplate"
                                        auto-startup="true"
                                        channel="channelB"
                                        topic="output"/>
      <bean id="dbsenderTemplate" class="org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <map>
                        <entry key="value.serializer" value="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"/>
                        <entry key="key.serializer" value="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"/>
                        <entry key="bootstrap.servers" value="localhost:9092"/>
                    </map>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="transactionIdPrefix" value="mytest-"/>
                <property name="producerPerConsumerPartition" value="false"/>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

The code that starts the app is as follows:

```
GenericXmlApplicationContext tempContext = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
tempContext.close();

//POINT A.

try {
  Thread.sleep(60000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}

GenericXmlApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
context.load("beans.xml");
context.refresh();

//POINT B
```

At **POINT A** I just closed the context to check which beans are closed, and put a 60 seconds sleep to have time to check the JMX console. I noticed that even though the context is closed but the producer is still registered in JMX. After that I traced the code and noticed that on context closing the **KafkaTemplate** calls the following code:

```
    public void flush() {
        Producer<K, V> producer = getTheProducer();
        try {
            producer.flush();
        }
        finally {
            closeProducer(producer, inTransaction());
        }
    }

    protected void closeProducer(Producer<K, V> producer, boolean inTx) {
        if (!inTx) {
            producer.close(this.closeTimeout);
        }
    }
```

It means it creates a producer but because it is transactional it will not be closed.

This behaviour makes that runnning the context again on **POINT B** and sending the message cause the `javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: kafka.producer:type=app-info,id=producer-mytest-0` Exception.
Why the KafkaTemplate does not close these producers?

And another question is what happens to these producers when a new KafkaTemplate is created on **POINT B**?

The last question is if I change the `producerPerConsumerPartition` property to `true` the mentioned app still registers producer Mbean with **producer-mytest-0** and does not follow the `groupid.topic.partition` pattern in naming. Is it a correct behaviour?

**UPDATES:**

I understood when the KafkaTemplate `executeInTransaction` is called. At the finally block it calls the close on the producer and as it is a logical close, the following code is called on the `CloseSafeProducer` and put it in the cache:

```
if (!this.cache.contains(this)
        && !this.cache.offer(this)) {
        this.delegate.close(closeTimeout);
        }
```

This makes when the context is closed the `destroy` method of `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` clears the cache and closes the producer physically. But in my situation application context is created but before consume and producing any message the context is closed, only the `flush` method of `KafkaTemplate` is called internally that force it to create a transactional producer but does not put it in the cache. As I didn't start a producer and KafkaTemplate do it on flush, is not it good that `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` put them in cache before using them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The producer cannot be closed if this template operation is participating in a transaction that was started outside of the template.

Even when closed, it is only "logically" closed - cached for reuse by another operation.

> Is it a correct behaviour?

Yes, for producer-initiated transactions; the alternative name is used when a consumer initiates the transaction.

The `InstanceAlreadyExistsException` problem is simply because you are creating two application contexts with identical configuration. Why are you doing that?

Comment: Thanks. I now understand the transaction name behaviour. I just updated the question about clearing the cache and closing the producer, Could you guide me in that?. Also, in my app the context will be closed and reloaded on situations like config file updates and any databse change. I do not want to stop the app, just reload the beans by reopening the context. I just do not understand that if the context is closing and I do not have started a transaction outside of template why the producer must remain open?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you closed the first context. It should work ok. The producer factory doesn't know what the producer was used for so it always caches them. I just tested it with the 2.5 kafka-clients and I see the MBeans being unregistered when the first context is closed.  If you can provide a complete, small example project that exhibits this behavior, I will take a loook.

Comment: As you tested and it was ok, I checked my spring-kafka version that was 2.3.6 and found that it had been fixed in 2.4.3 in KafkaTemplate.getTheProducer() by the assertion. Thanks alot